# Email.less is pulling in theme.less adding unnecessary styles to sales emails

Tags: magento2, less

Email.less is pulling in theme.less adding unnecessary styles to sales emails.

This is happening in our parent blank theme in the vendor folder. Is there a way to kill the @import so its not being pulled into email.less without editing "core?"

There is also a theme.less in our custom theme.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can copy the file that has the **@import** to your theme, so to change using the override file.

**to**

```
vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/email.less
```

**from**

```
app/design/frontend/[Theme]/[Package]/web/css/email.less
```

If you want apply something only on the Sales templates, you can override the file below.

> vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/Magento_Sales/web/css/source/_email.less